# dynamic array allocation, pointers, min, max, avg, sum

Tags: arrays, c, class, pointers, minmax

I have been trying to run this code and keep getting segmentation faults, but the array does print.
What the heck am I doing wrong?
I believe the problem is somewhere in main with the format of functions or with the parameters I am putting in the functions, I have tried so many ways but nothing I have tried seems to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void fillArray(int arr[], int arr_size);
void printArray(int arr[], int arr_size);
void fMin(int arr[], int arr_size, int *q);
void fMax(int arr[], int arr_size, int *p);
void fSum(int arr[], int arr_size, int *x);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *arr=NULL;
    int arr_size = atoi(argv[1]);
    arr = malloc(arr_size * sizeof(int));

    if(argc <= 2)
    {
        printf("ERROR: invalid command line args");
        printf("Expecting: EXCECUTABLE <SIZE>");
    }

    fillArray(arr, arr_size);

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
    {
        printf("argv[%d] - %2d", arr_size, arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printArray(arr, arr_size);

    int *min, *max ,avg, sum;
    int *p;
    int *q;
    int *x;
    avg = sum / arr_size;

    fMax(arr, arr_size, p);
    fMin(arr, arr_size, q);
    fSum(arr, arr_size, &sum);

    printf("Max: %3d Pos: %3d \n", *max, *p);
    printf("Min: %3d Pos: %3d \n", *min, *q);
    printf("Sum: %3d \n", *x);
    printf("Avg: %3d \n", avg);

    //for realloc! printArray(arr, arr_size);

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

void fillArray(int arr[], int arr_size)
{
     srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 101;
    }
}//good!

void printArray(int arr[], int arr_size)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf(" POS | VAL \n");
    printf("-----------\n");
    for(i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
    {
         printf(" %3d | %3d \n", i, arr[i]);
     }
}//good!

void fMin(int arr[], int arr_size, int *q)
{
    int i;
    int *min=NULL;
    min=&arr[i];
    for(i=1; i<arr_size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] < *min)
        {
            min = &arr[i];
            q = &i;
        } 
    }
}//cant null pointer

void fMax(int arr[], int arr_size, int *p)
{
    int i;
    int *max=NULL;
    max = &arr[i];
        for(i=1; i<arr_size; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > *max)
            {
                max = &arr[i];
                p = &i;
            } 
        }
}//good?
void fSum(int arr[], int arr_size, int *x)
{
    int i;
    int sum = *x;
    for (i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
    {
        *x = i + arr[i];
    }
}//what  the  heckie goin on here
```

I run"./a.out 5 6"

and it outputs:

```
argv[5] - 31
argv[5] - 13
argv[5] - 27
argv[5] - 83
argv[5] - 23
 POS | VAL 
-----------
   0 |  31 
   1 |  13 
   2 |  27 
   3 |  83 
   4 |  23 
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out 5 6
```

Comment: i am also supposed to reallocate the array later on hence the two args, but havent got that far due to not being able to figure this portion out

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Also, step through the code in the debugger to see what's happening. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning. There is no better tool available to a programmer to step through the execution of code, monitor the value of variables, and find logic errors. *I have an error somewhere in this code dump* isn't a reasonable question.

Comment: fair enough ken but i did state that i had problems with the function calls and the parameters but i will give it a shot

Comment: What you wrote was *I believe the problem is somewhere in main with the format of functions or with the parameters I am putting in the functions*, which is the same as *Somewhere in main with the format of functions or parameters or somewhere else entirely, there's a problem.*

Comment: how should i format the questions? how to poppulate a min function with pointers?

Comment: this is my first post take it easy man

Comment: You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. We're not a generic *Here's my code. Debug it for me.* site - we expect you to make an effort to figure things out yourself first, and that includes basic debugging efforts.

Comment: fair enough thanks for your helpful answer

Comment: You have two lines `printf("argv[%d] - %2d", arr_size, arr[i]);` and `printf("\n");` — These could be combined, and your output would be more informative if you passed `i` rather than `arr_size` — as in `printf("argv[%d] = %2d\n", i, arr[i]);`.

Comment: appreciate it, that makes sense i unsure why i decided to put the newline on another printf, how are the printf functions, i tried &p,&q with %3p and %3d and also *p,*q, and p,q with %3d and %3p but i keep outputting fx34829 numbers but i need the pos of the array value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of your problems lie in the lines:

```
int *min, *max, avg, sum;
int *p;
int *q;
int *x;
avg = sum / arr_size;

fMax(arr, arr_size, p);
fMin(arr, arr_size, q);
fSum(arr, arr_size, &sum);
```

You pass the uninitialized pointers `p` and `q` to `fMax()` and `fMin()`; that's a recipe for crashing.  You calculate the average before calculating the sum (so `sum` is uninitialized).

You need code more like:

```
int min, max, avg, sum;

fMax(arr, arr_size, &max);
fMin(arr, arr_size, &min);
fSum(arr, arr_size, &sum);
avg = sum / arr_size;
```

I've not checked the functions, but the calls were definitely bogus.

*[…time passeth…]*

There are problems in the functions too.  For example, in `fMin()`, it isn't entirely clear whether you are passing back the index of the minimum value or the actual minimum value, but there are problems galore.

You have:

```
void fMin(int arr[], int arr_size, int *q)
{
    int i;
    int *min=NULL;
    min=&arr[i];
    for(i=1; i<arr_size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] < *min)
        {
            min = &arr[i];
            q = &i;
        } 
    }
}
```

The line `min = &arr[i];` uses an uninitialized variable, `i`, to index into the array.  Local variables in C are not magically initialized to zero!  There's no point in initializing `min` to `NULL` and immediately setting it to something else.  You could use:

```
int *min = &arr[0];
```

Theoretically, you should check that `arr_size` is bigger than zero before doing that.

Your assignment `q = &i;` means you can no longer relay any information back to the calling code — you've lost the pointer to the variable in the calling function.

You should probably use code more like this (where you'd need to include `<limits.h>` to get `INT_MAX`):

```
void fMin(int arr[], int arr_size, int *pmin)
{
    if (arr_size <= 0)
    {
        *pmin = INT_MAX;
        return;
    }
    int min = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
    }
    *pmin = min;
}
```

This returns the minimum value.  If you want the index of the first element containing the minimum value, you change the code a bit:

```
void fMin(int arr[], int arr_size, int *pmin)
{
    if (arr_size <= 0)
    {
        *pmin = INT_MAX;
        return;
    }
    int min = arr[0];
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
            idx = i;
        }
    }
    *pmin = idx;
}
```

If you want the index of the last entry containing the minimum value, you change the test to `if (arr[i] <= min)`.  Another sensible change would have the function return the minimum value, or the index of the minimum value, instead of taking a pointer to hold the return value.

There are analogous problems with `fMax()`.

The code in `fSum()` should probably be like this:

```
int fSum(int arr[], int arr_size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
        sum += arr[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Here I've changed the code to return the result.  Note that this is vulnerable to arithmetic overflow, which leads to undefined behaviour.  However, you're probably not going to run into that as a problem.

Comment: thank you, so if i have the pointers titled in the fMax, fMin functions i have to redefine them in the main?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking — and I was busy deconstructing and reconstructing your functions when you asked.  You have to pass pointers to actual variables to the functions if they're going to receive values back.  The simplest way to do that is to use `&min` etc.  An alternative would be to have `int *p = &min;` and pass `p` to the function — but that's modestly silly.  The pointer `p` has no other use, so you may as well pass `&min` directly.  In other contexts, using an intermediate pointer variable might be sensible, but not here.

Comment: well this is the second assignment, the first was exactly like this but using only variables and I am to use pointers for this but i guess i dont really understand the whole concept.

Comment: my professor and all the videos i have watched said to initialize the pointers and set them to null, then use the & to get the position. but i feel i am trying to overcomplecate this assignment by using too many pointers would you agree with that being the case? i am still new to coding this is my second class csc250, csc150 was first and i am not really sure what to be asking no matter how many videos and lectures i have watched i just dont understand and that is a me problem but if you could help with explaining pointers to me that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: i dont think i am allowed to use <limits.h> as we have not learned that

Comment: Now is an excellent opportunity to do some learning on your own, then.  However, you can use `enum { INT_MAX = 2147483647 };` if you're not allowed to use `<limits.h>`, but that's really quite silly.  It assumes that `int` values are 32 bits long.

Comment: I guess you've not been watching the best videos, and neither has your professor.  I'm also assuming there are some videos out there that don't spout that advice.  Initializing pointers is a good idea, but initializing them to null only to assign a different value in the next line is silly.  And using pointer variables where `&var` does what is required is likewise silly.  The rules are not formally wrong, but you would lose points off your grade if I'm marking the homework (but I wouldn't have taught you to do things that way anyhow).  _[…Diatribe continued…]_

Comment: _[…Continuation of diatribe…]_ Using pointers in the interface to the functions is OK; that's why I didn't change the interface for `fMin()`.  But you need to distinguish between what's written in the function and what's written in the calling function (`main()` in your exercise).  In the function, `pmin` is a pointer to where the result will be stored.  You assign `*pmin = new_value;` to change the value visible in the calling code.  In the calling function, you pass `&min` or `int *p = &min;` and pass `p` to the function. When the function assigns to `*pmin`, it changes `min` in `main()`.